# How to find the cloud_RoleInstance of an Azure App service web app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

I have an application that consists of a few different Azure App Service apps all running on the same App Service Plan. I am sending telemetry data from all the apps to one instance of Application Insights (backed by one LogAnalytics instance). In the requests and traces I am trying to determine the best way to differentiate the logs between different services.

I plan on setting the cloudRoleName per app which will help, but there is also a cloudRoleInstace number which is populated automatically with something like dw0********P9.

How can I find which app this number refers to? I cant find the number on the app service portal page anywhere.

Comment: What is cloud_RoleInstance btw?

Answer (score 1):

Azure set some environment vars that Applications Insights will consume, if present.

Take a look at docs:

[Azure App Service Environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/reference-app-settings?tabs=kudu%2Cnode)

You can check the source code either, where appInsights is reading the values of environments vars:

[AppInsights Config.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-node.js/blob/3d1438b14cbf4dcb4ae1d614fbb4f990ee43b15b/Library/Config.ts)

Comment: Thank you for this I was able to find where the number is coming from. It is the machine name of the app and also set on a couple of default envrionment variables on the app which are all visible on the Kudu environment page.

COMPUTERNAME and USERNAME env vars.

Answer (score 0):

After the post above from @Jone Polvora. I was able to decipher that the number in the `cloud_RoleInstance` field is visible from the environment page within Kudu for the app. It is the machine name on that page but also set as the following environment variables by default.

`COMPUTERNAME` and `USERNAME`